# how to do 2.5 Animation in java(Android)

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I need to do 2.5d animation in java on an android platform but don't know where to start from. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of the type of 2.5d display you mean? E.g. isometric projection with oblique up/down/left/right motion.